# Probability that a jar with 200 jelly beans with 40 colors has at least one of every color.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to calculate the probability that a jar with 200 jelly beans and 40 possible jelly bean colors does not feature all colors at least 1 time.

I am aware of the way to solve this using inclusion-exclusion but have been wondering why the following approach does not work.

Let 40 glasses represent the 40 different colors. Now calculate the number of ways in which you can sort jelly beans into these glasses. This is similar to the question of in how many ways we can write 200 as a sum of 40 non-zero integers. The answer to this should be $239\choose 39$.

Now calculate the number of ways to distribute with at least one jelly bean in each glass. Remove 40 jelly beans and add one to each glass. Then we have 160 jelly beans left that we can distribute arbitrarily in any of $199 \choose 39$ ways.

Dividing the latter by the former gives a number close to 0, however, which is clearly wrong. Where am I going wrong with this approach?

Comment: This is not clear.  What's the probability distribution of the colors?

Comment: Regardless of the details, it's seldom possible to use Stars and Bars for probability, since the configurations are (usually) not equally probable.

Comment: You are totally right, I did not think about that we cannot apply this reasoning here! Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you'd have to know how many jelly beans are each color.  If one color is really rare it could be really unlikely, if they all occur with equal frequency it's much more likely.

Comment: You might find it useful to read about the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Rather than phrase it as a probability problem, you could phrase it as a combinatorics problem: "How many distinguishable jars of 200 jelly beans can be made from 40 colors of jelly beans (which are distinguishable only by color)? How many of those jars have at least one jelly bean of every color?" If you then add the assumption that each of the first set of jars is equally likely, your probability question becomes answerable.